# Question about Google Colab Transformer Tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, transformer-model

I'm trying to follow the Tensorflow Transformer tutorial here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/text/blob/master/docs/tutorials/transformer.ipynb

In the tutorial, they reproduce the image of the Transformer model from the original "Attention is All You Need" paper. In the image the final layers of the Transformer model are a Dense layer followed by Softmax Activation. However in the code I only see something like this:

`self.final_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(target_vocab_size)`

where the Dense layer is defined. But I cannot find the Softmax Activation applied anywhere in the tutorial.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the notebook more carefully, I see that the loss function is calculated as:

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction='none')
```

As explained in the link below, setting *from_logits* to *True* ensures that the Softmax is applied during the loss calculation.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/73093/what-does-from-logits-true-do-in-sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-loss-function

So the Softmax activation does not need to be applied within the Dense layer of the Transformer model.